# Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(None, 299, 299, 3), dtype=float32) at layer "input_1"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to use heatmaps for `Xception` model (with modified top layer):

```python
import tensorflow as to
import cv2
import numpy as np
label = 1
IMAGE_PATH = '/home/piyush/Desktop/HV/hv_2/deep-viz-keras/images/doberman.png'

img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(IMAGE_PATH, target_size=(299, 299))
img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)

model_path = '/home/piyush/Desktop/temp/model.h5'
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(299,299,3))
#print(model.summary())
#print([layer.shape for layer in model.get_layer('xception').layers])
final = tf.keras.Model(inputs=model.inputs, outputs=model.output)
print(model.inputs)
#extractor = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[layer.output for layer in model.layers])
conv_layer = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=model.get_layer('xception').get_layer('block14_sepconv2_act').output)
```

If I run this, I got the following error:

```
        conv_layer = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=model.get_layer('xception').get_layer('block14_sepconv2_act').output)

ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(None, 299, 299, 3), dtype=float32) at layer "input_1". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

Comment: your inputs variable is not connected to the model at all.

Answer (score 0):

You define

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(299,299,3))
```

but then never use this variable in the model. You probably simply want

```
inputs = model.inputs
```

since you are loading an existing model, not creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED :

`conv_layer = tf.keras.Model(inputs= model.get_layer('xception').inputs,outputs=model.get_layer('xception').get_layer('block14_sepconv2_act').output)`

The reason that the model is disconnected so the input and output should be of same model.